Как с помощью google script сделать нажатие нескольких чекбоксов, при нажатии на "главный чекбокс" и при определенных условиях в соседних ячейках?

Доброго времени, пытаюсь реализовать групповое нажатие чекбоксов, работать это должно следующим образом: Например есть таблица где три колонки A,B,C. Чекбоксы находятся в колонке "C".
При нажатии чекбокса и установив ему истина или ложь, если в этой же строке в колонке "B" пустое значение, то нужно выделить диапазон по колонке "С" вниз до строки, где будет тоже пустое значение в колонке "B" и проставить для всего диапазона тоже самое значение(истина или ложь).
Пытался сделать это формулой но ничего не получается, с учетом того что строки постоянно меняются, удаляются и добавляются новые. Думаю что можно решить эту задачу с помощью onEdit и не могу сообразить и написать логику алгоритма, прошу помощи и навести на нужные мысли.

Какие-либо табличные формулы не помогут в данной задаче.
А вот google-script через onEdit - вполне реализуемая задача.
Алгоритм довольно прост, и их можно сочинить несколько.
Но самое главное, что является базой - это надо определить ключевые строки, т.е. те, в которых есть слово "Группа" в ячейке А (возможны и другие варианты слов, которые можно использовать как ключевые, и они определяют группировку).
Ну а далее самый простейший алгоритм, когда нажимают чекбокс в групповой (Ключевой строке) и сразу меняются все чек-боксы в этой подгруппе.

Срабатывает onEdit:

сразу проверяем, этот лист или нет. Если нет - выходим из скрипта.
выделяем строку-диапазон, где сработал триггер - var selectedRange =
Проверяем ячейку А на ключевое слово (в данном случае "Группа"). Если нет - выходим из скрипта.


Если первичная проверка прошла, то продолжаем:

записываем текущее значение ячейки С в промежуточную переменную типа CurrentVar.
перебираем строки вниз:

если в следующей строке в ячейке А нет ключевого слова "Группа", тогда в ячейку С записываем промежуточное значение CurrentVar.
если в следующей строке в ячейке А есть ключевое слово "Группа", тогда заканчиваем скрипт.
если в следующей строке в ячейке А вообще нет никаких слов, т.е. пустая, значит дошли до конца списка и заканчиваем скрипт.






Добрый день. По опыту знаю - не всего в наименовании товара может содержаться одно ключевое слово. Я бы сделала технический столбец, где бы указывалось количество строк в данной группе и через него уже проставляла бы "галочки". А так ответ достойный!

Очень полезное дополнение! Респект!
Это правда, если в Групповых строках названия ячейки "А" будут меняться и не будет каких-либо постоянных ключевых символов или слов - тогда очевидно нужно будет вводить дополнительную техническую колонку, которая бы однозначно определяла бы строку, как групповую.
В одной из разработок для такой цели - идентификации строки как группы, я использовал примечание ячейки с одним постоянным символом.   Скрипт совсем немного усложнился, но получилось прикольно.
В этом случае обошлось без лишних технических столбиков

Тоже хороший вариант.
